# Proof of Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem in big Rudin

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

In big Rudin's book, the proof of [Riesz's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) quite confuses me. It states that the definition of  $\mu_1(V)=\mbox{sup}\{Lf:f\prec V\}$ and $\mu_2(V)=\mbox{inf}\{\mu_1(U): V\subset U, U \ \mbox{is open}\}$ is equivalent for all $V\subset X$, where $X$ is a topological space

---

It is obvious that when $V$ is open. For general $V$, it is not difficult to prove $\mu_2(V)\leq\mu_1(V)$, but I don't know how to prove the opposite direction.

Comment: $\mu_1$ is defined only for open sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am also quite confused about the first definition. If $\mu_1(V)$ is $\infty$, then it is impossible that $\mu_1(V)\leq Lf+\epsilon$ according to the definition of supremum

Comment: Using $\epsilon$ works only if the supremum is finite. Take the proper definition of the supremum, 1) for all $f \prec V$ we have $Lf \leqslant \mu_1(V)$, and 2) for all $c < \mu_1(V)$ there is an $f \prec V$ with $c < Lf$.